Can't double hold an int value?
I'm receiving data from an API that provides a weather info, for simplicity i will provide just an attribute of the received data:
final double feels_like;

and in json deserialization:
feels_Like = json['main']['feels_like']

But i got that Exception : type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double', actually i solved it (using toDouble()) no problem here, the problem is in the following concept.
Suppose the returned value is an int, can't a double hold it?
for example:
double feels_like = 30.1; // ok
double feels_like = 30; // also ok

Both data types are sub types of base num class and a double object can holds an int object but not vice versa.
So, Why is that happening while working with the API even if it returns an int.

No, a variable of type double cannot hold an int.
It is just that integer literals are automatically converted to doubles when necessary.
The following is an error:
double feels_like = 30 as int; // not allowed

int x = 30;
double y = x; // not allowed

If you want a type that can hold either double or int values, then declare the type as num.
num feels_like = 30 as int; // allowed

int x = 30;
num y = x; // allowed

num z = 3.7; // allowed


i understand , each type has its own attributes and behaviors (after extending num) which is common between them (they are different)  print(int is double) will be false and vice versa. but imagine that line of code feels_Like = json['main']['feels_like'] which will be feels_Like = 20  20 here will be treated as double value like 20.0 , why it can't be assigned.

the automatic conversion applies only to literals.

isn't 20 a literal .

20 is a literal, json['main']['feels_like'] is not.

thanks, appreciated.
